# iOS - Problems with memory and retain/release

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, instruments

I had developed an app and now I'm using Instruments to see the memory usage. I have a problem understanding the retain/release process of my object. This is what Instruments says:

[image]

The retain count increase when I add my object into an array, when I add it on my view and when I take off from the array.
So, when I use `removeFromSuperview` the object `retainCount` will never be zero, so the object don't release the memory.

EDIT 1:
I forgot to say i'm using ARC.

EDIT 2:
I describe exactly what happen :
I create the object together other objects in a class called `NKLevelGenerator`. Into it i alloc the `NKIngredient`s and then i add all to a `NSArray` which will be returned. Here the retain count of every object is 2. In my `NKLevelVC`, my `ViewController`, i use this instruction :

```
[level addObjectsFromArray:[levelGenerator level1WithDelegate:self ciotola:ciotola bagliore:bagliore difficulty:NKDifficultyHard]];
```

Object `level` is a `NSMutableArray` that i `alloc` and `init` in `viewDidLoad`.
From here i call another method which performs this operations :

```
- (void)insertInArrayRandomly {
    for (int i=0; i<[level count]; i++) {
        [ingredienti insertObject:[level objectAtIndex:[[indexes objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]] atIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Object `ingredienti` is another `NSMutableArray` that I `alloc` and `init` in `viewDidLoad`. `indexes` is an array of `NSInteger` which contains random indexes to extract `NKIngredient` object randomly.
Then i'm doing this :

```
NKIngredient *ing = [ingredienti objectAtIndex:index];
[[self view] insertSubview:ing belowSubview:navBar];
[ing animateIngredient];
[ingredienti removeObject:ing];
```

Comment: Here is the image : http://f.cl.ly/items/1Y2Z1e2K3e3Y3e1I1z26/Schermata%202012-12-19%20alle%2011.18.51.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before looking into Instruments have you tried the Static Analysis of your code? It may help for simple memory problems.

But the very first thing to check is: Did you follow the **Golden Rule**?

The Golden Rule being: For each `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` you must use one, and only one, `release`or `autorelease`.

This is the most important rule for memory management without ARC. So the fact that you object is retained by th array is none of your business, just remember what you have retained, allocated or copied and release it.

PS: Next time, your code would be much more helpful than the Instruments screenshot.

Comment: I'm using ARC in this project

Comment: So you should not use `retain` nor `release`... What does the Static Analysis says?

Comment: Static Analysis says there's no memory leak! But the object remain in memory, i see this through Instruments.

Comment: Is your object stored in a `strong` property?

Comment: Not directly. My object is into an array. I have a class which returns an array of NKIngredient objects. From this array I move the elements into another, then i add one by one to my view and i animate it through an NSTimer. When elements are ready to hide i remove it from superview using [ingredient removeFromSuperview]. So, i don't declare it as a property, should I do it?

Comment: As I see it, your object is still in your array, that's why it's still retained. Each time something (an array, a view, etc.) is keeping a reference on your object, it is retained, so when you do `NKIngredient *ing = [ingredienti objectAtIndex:index];` your object is still in the array, so it is still retained. That makes sense.

Comment: When you empty your array, it will be released.

Comment: The NKIngredient objects was in 2 different arrays. I remove all from the second array, but not from the first, this is the reason of the memory problems! Removing elements from array decrease its retainCount.

Answer (score 0):

First: use instruments to see if effectively there's a memory leak, there's a tool made for this purpose and it tells you where you leak memory.
Second: it depend on how many object made [retain] on the view. If you add to an Array, it retain the view, but if you don't release it in the method that create the view, when you release the view from the array, the count will still be 1.